# Exporting of Animated gif from polar plot

Tags: export, animation

I want to export an animation(gif type) for polar plot $r=\cos 2\theta$ like to the following gif. how can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 9):

`rose = Table[PolarPlot[Cos[x i], {i, 0, Pi}, PlotRange -> 1], {x, 0, 10, .1}];`

Followed by:

`Export["rose.gif", rose]`

Which gives you the following beautiful animation:

[image]

You can change the final number of petals by changing the number `10`. You can change the speed of the animation by making the increments smaller than `.1`.

Answer (score 8):

To realize the constant-speed drawing, you'll need to re-parameterize the equation to use the **arc-length** parameter:

$$
\mathrm{d}s = \left\| \frac{\mathrm{d}\,\boldsymbol{\mathrm{r}}(\theta)}{\mathrm{d}\theta}\right\|\mathrm{d}\theta
$$

```
r = Cos[2 θ] {Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}
reParaEq = θ'[s] == 1/FullSimplify[Sqrt[#.#] &@D[r, θ] /. θ -> θ[s]]
θFunc = DSolveValue[{reParaEq, θ[0] == 0}, θ, s][s]
(* And the max value of the arc-length: *)
{sMax} = s /. Solve[θFunc == 2 π, s]
```

To actually plotting the expected result, we need to turn off `MaxRecursion`:

```
wholePlot = ParametricPlot[Evaluate[r /. θ -> θFunc], {s, 0, sMax},
                           PlotPoints -> 200, MaxRecursion -> 0
                          ]
frames = wholePlot /. ({Line[pts_] :> Line[pts[[;; #]]]} & /@ Range[200]);
```

To show the animation in Mathematica, we can use `ListAnimate`:

```
ListAnimate[frames, 60]
```

To export it as GIF:

```
Export["FourLeaveRose.gif", frames, "GIF", "DisplayDurations" -> 1/60, AnimationRepetitions -> ∞]
```

[image: four leave rose]

Comment: To @Silvia Why is your code hard and exotic?!!! Please look at my code in my answer.

Comment: @bigli It's not exotic at all... just normal [differential geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length) -- Basically, the so-called *natural parameterization* walks along the curve with speed proportionally to **arc-length** $s$, so will force `Plot` using **equally distributed** sampled points. (But yes, this effect may not be what you required.) The second benefit of my method would be only invoking `Plot` once, which is more efficient. Also, I would like to point out the `"DisplayDurations"` option of GIF export, in case it might be handy for you.

Answer (score 4):

**BE HAPPY!!** The easiest code is:

```
a:=
Show[PolarPlot[Cos[2 \[Theta]], {\[Theta], 0, t}], 
PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
b= ParallelTable[a, {t, 0.001, 2 Pi, (2 Pi - 0.001)/100}];
Export["4-leaved-rose.gif",b ]
```

and the result is:

[image]

Comment: Look at both of them. you should find out difference of them. My answer is just answer of the principal question.

Comment: You should read Aron's answer more carefully, he shows you how you can write a better code which is even simpler. Another simple one-liner: `b = PolarPlot[Cos[2 [Theta]], {\[Theta], $MachineEpsilon, #}, PlotRange -> 1] & /@ Range[0, 2 Pi, 0.02 Pi];`